# Unexpected Power Loss Count meaning in SMART

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart, crystaldiskinfo

I have bought a brand new HP SSD, I use it for backups and do that by opening the case and install it as a secondary drive.
Recently, I ran CrystalDiskInfo and found out a really weird indicator *AE - Unexpected Power Loss Count* to be equal to 0x18 (24 in decimal) which is weird given that I never had power outages when I used it or at least not that number, others are normal like power on hours which is 7.

Could be caused by Windows not shutting it down when I turn off the PC. And if it is caused by that, how can I force it to turn its power off?

Comment: What are you even asking? Could it be Windows? Yes, sure. Now what? Question reads like a chat question.

Comment: I edited my question, how to force Windows to turn the power off before shutting it down.

Answer (score 1):

#### AE - Unexpected Power Loss Count to be equal to 0x18

It is nothing to worry about:

> **Description**
>
> Unexpected Power Loss S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates a number of
> unexpected power loss events.
>
> **Recommendations**
>
> This parameter is considered informational by the most hardware
> vendors. Although degradation of this parameter can be an indicator of
> drive aging and/or potential electromechanical problems, it does not
> directly indicate imminent drive failure. Regular backup is
> recommended. Pay closer attention to other parameters and overall
> drive health.

Source: [S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: Unexpected Power Loss | Knowledge Base](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9169?ckattempt=1)

Comment: Informative but what is its cause, is Windows not powering it off correctly?